# Data isnt being sent to DB after registering

Tags: php, mysql

When I click submit it sends me to the header location which confirms the user they have signed up but the data isn't being sent to the database so you cant login after signing up, not sure what is wrong I had it working earlier, cant find my mistake. Some help would be appreciated!

```
<form action = "Register.php" method="POST">
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$Fname = $_POST['Fname'];
$Lname = $_POST['Lname'];
$Display1 = $_POST['Display1'];
$Display2 = $_POST['Display2'];
if(empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($email) || empty($Fname) || empty($Lname) || empty($Display1)) {
    echo '<p>Fields Empty!</p>';
} else if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username' AND password ='$password'");
    echo'<p>Username or Password Already Exists!</p>';
} else {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(id, username, password, Display1, Display2, email, Fname, Lname, user_level, type) VALUES (``, '$username', '$password', '$Display1', '$Display2', '$email', '$Fname', '$Lname', '2', 'a')");

            $subject = "Membership Confirmation";
            $message = "Hello, You have registered an account on ";
            $from = "From: ";

            header("location:signuppayment.php");
            mail($email, $subject, $message, $from);
}

}

?>
<fieldset>
<legend>Register</legend>
<label>Username: <input class="text" type="text" name="username" /></label>
<label>Password: <input class="text" type="password" name="password" />   </label>
<label>Email: <input class="text" type="text" name="email" /></label>
<label>First name: <input class="text" type="text" name="Fname" /></label>
<label>Last name: <input class="text" type="text" name="Lname" /></label>
<label>Display name 1: <input class="text" type="text" name="Display1" />  </label>
<label>Display name 2: <input class="text" type="text" name="Display2" /></label>

</fieldset>
<div class ="registerForm">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

Comment: you have a strong desire to be hacked i see

Comment: `} else if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){` before $query is defined - php can not break the space time continuum

Comment: not really sure how that helps...

Comment: the mysql_* functions are deprecated, pick another mysql extension/API, see http://docs.php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing . After picking an API (my weapon of choice is PDO) check how the error handling is done - and add it to your script! Also have a read of http://php.net/security.database.sql-injection

Comment: to clarify on what @Dagon stated, a) don't use `mysql_` extensions (they are deprecated)  b) either escape your variables, or better c) use prepared statements.

Comment: thanks but is there a reason why the data wont submit to db

Comment: also, for the other comment, it's not possible to check whether you have any rows in your query before you run the query.   there's nothing to check.   Not breaking the space-time continuum actually means something here.  In other words, you cant check something that does not exist yet

Comment: "but is there a reason why the data wont submit to db" - maybe there's an error in your sql statement, maybe it's something else; error handling could tell. But since there are quite a bunch of other things .....fix-worthy you'd better start over with another api. And that goes for your other questions as well.

Comment: you are calling `$query` before you have defined it

Comment: fixed that it still doesnt work

Comment: @VolkerK thanks i didnt realize how big a deal it was, Im still new to this so learning as i go

Comment: A suggestion: As a starting point switch to PDO, set the error reporting to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION and use prepared statements with named parameters (no more string concatenation in sql queries until you know why and how ;-)). Also consider my previous answer regarding using a unique key instead of the "SELECT <username already used>"-and-then-INSERT construct. It's really prone to race conditions and the unique key thingy isn't that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with following;

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$Fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Fname']);
$Lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Lname']);
$Display1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Display1']);
$Display2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Display2']);
if(empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($email) || empty($Fname) || empty($Lname) || empty($Display1)) {
    echo '<p>Fields Empty!</p>';
    //set your header location here if you want to tell the user the fields are empty incase you have seprate php action file;
    //exit;
} 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username' AND password ='$password'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
    echo'<p>Username or Password Already Exists!</p>';
    //set your header location here if you want to tell the user that username and password already exist incase you have seprate php action file;
    //exit;
    } else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(id, username, password, Display1, Display2, email, Fname, Lname, user_level, type) VALUES (``, '$username', '$password', '$Display1', '$Display2', '$email', '$Fname', '$Lname', '2', 'a')");
            //You can also set if statement here so to be sure that email triggered after successfull data insertion
            $subject = "Membership Confirmation";
            $message = "Hello, You have registered an account on ";
            $from = "From: ";

            mail($email, $subject, $message, $from);
    }
            header("location:signuppayment.php");
            exit;
}
?>

//you can set inputs 'required' like this to be sure no empty field submitted, better use jQuery or javascript for validation.
<input class="text" type="text" name="username" required />
```

Comment: thanks a lot really cleared things up, but i do need to stop using mysql_ statements, ill make the switch.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like...

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if($db->connect_errno) {
    die('Sorry, there is trouble making database connections at the moment.');
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']){
    if(empty($_POST['username']) 
    || empty($_POST['password']) 
    || empty($_POST['email']) 
    || empty($_POST['Fname']) 
    || empty($_POST['Lname']) 
    || empty($_POST['Display1'])
    || empty($_POST['Display2'])) {

        echo '<p>Please make sure all fields are filled.</p>';

    } else {

        $check = $db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = {$username}");

        if($check->num_rows) {
            echo 'Username taken.';
        } else {

        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, Display1, Display2, email, Fname, Lname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $query->bind_param('sssssss', $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['Display1'], $_POST['Display2'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['Fname'], $_POST['Lname']);
        $query->execute();
        header("location:signuppayment.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting error when trying to load page, "Trying to get property of non-object"  for the final IF statement and "Call to a member function param() on null " for the bind_param. I have been looking into it but it seems fine to me which is why Im confused its spitting out an error.

Comment: Try: if($check->num_rows > 0)

Comment: no, still getting same errors